# Property 'self.navigation' not initialized at super.init call

Tags: swift

How do I open a ViewController from `@IBAction`. In below `@IBAction` I tried to open a ViewController but I am getting `Property 'self.navigation' not initialized at super.init call` error:

```
 // MARK: - IBActions
    @IBAction func doAddCard() {
        // OTHER CODE GOES HERE
        
        let viewController = PaymentsStoryboard.confirmKyc()
        navigation.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
        
       //...    
}
```

Full Code:

```
import UIKit

final class ManualCardAddView: UIView, XibInitializable, DialogKeyboardDelegate {
    
    var completionHandler: ((CreditCard, String) -> Void)?
    private unowned let navigation: UINavigationController
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }
    
    private func setup() {
        loadFromXib()
        
        // ...
    }
    
    @IBAction func doAddCard() {
        
        let viewController = PaymentsStoryboard.confirmKyc()
        navigation.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
        
        // ...
    }
}
```

How do I resolve above issue?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `navigation` to a mutable optional property, since it only gets set *after* the initialisation. All immutable properties (and mutable non-optional ones as well) must be set during initialisation.

So change

```
private unowned let navigation: UINavigationController
```

to

```
private unowned var navigation: UINavigationController?
```

Comment: Thank you, now I am getting this error: `Value of optional type 'UINavigationController?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'pushViewController' of wrapped base type 'UINavigationController'`

Comment: and as I do `navigation!.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)` I get that above error again

Comment: @MirStephen are you actually setting a value to `navigation`? Optional unwrapping `navigation` should resolve the compiler errors anyways, what error are you getting when doing `navigation?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)`?

Comment: when I do above code your just commented, I get below same error again: `Property 'self.navigation' not initialized at super.init call`

Comment: @MirStephen you shouldn't need to, but try assigning a `nil` default value, like `private unowned var navigation: UINavigationController? = nil`

Comment: the error is now gone, but some reasons it didn't navigate to storyboard, will check on that. Thank You for help